# Very strange Mysql query optimization

Tags: mysql-5.7

This is the initial query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT clienti.id_cliente AS cliente_id , clienti.cognome AS cognome,clienti.nome AS nome     
FROM
    clienti
WHERE
     clienti.id_agenzia = 5782 AND clienti.deleted = 0 AND (clienti.cognome LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.nome LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.ragione_sociale LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.indirizzo LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.email LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.email2 LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.email_pec LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.note LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.tel LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.tel2 LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.cell LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.fax LIKE '%marco%') ORDER BY cognome ASC, nome ASC, cliente_id LIMIT 0, 500
```

which takes 5.7 seconds on my VPS server (16 GB Ram, 8 cores). Table "clienti" contains 2.8 Milion recors.

this is the explain results:

```
id  select_type     table       partitions  type    possible_keys    key                                                  key_len   ref     rows    filtered    Extra   
1   SIMPLE          clienti     NULL        index   id_agenzia-id_agente-external_id_cliente,cognome-n...   cognome-nome    306     NULL    22223   0.28        Using where
```

I try this:

```
SELECT cliente_id, cognome, nome FROM (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT clienti.id_cliente AS cliente_id , clienti.cognome AS cognome,clienti.nome AS nome     
    FROM
        clienti
    WHERE
         clienti.id_agenzia = 5782 AND clienti.deleted = 0 AND (clienti.cognome LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.nome LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.ragione_sociale LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.indirizzo LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.email LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.email2 LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.email_pec LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.note LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.tel LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.tel2 LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.cell LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.fax LIKE '%marco%') ORDER BY cognome ASC, nome ASC, cliente_id LIMIT 0, 500 ) AS tb1
```

explain:

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys                                           key            key_len  ref     rows    filtered    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  NULL        ALL     NULL                                                      NULL           NULL   NULL    500     100.00  NULL
2   DERIVED     clienti     NULL        index   id_agenzia-id_agente-external_id_cliente,cognome-n...   cognome-nome    306     NULL    22223   0.28        Using where
```

nothing changes.

Then I try:

```
SELECT cliente_id, cognome, nome FROM (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT clienti.id_cliente AS cliente_id , clienti.cognome AS cognome,clienti.nome AS nome     
    FROM
        clienti
    WHERE
         clienti.id_agenzia = 5782 AND clienti.deleted = 0 AND (clienti.cognome LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.nome LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.ragione_sociale LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.indirizzo LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.email LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.email2 LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.email_pec LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.note LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.tel LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.tel2 LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.cell LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.fax LIKE '%marco%') 
ORDER BY cognome ASC, nome ASC, cliente_id 

) AS tb1
LIMIT 0, 500
```

explain:

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys                                           key                                         key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  NULL        ALL     NULL                                                    NULL                                        NULL        NULL    4568    100.00      NULL
2   DERIVED     clienti     NULL        ref     id_agenzia-id_agente-external_id_cliente,cognome-n...   id_agenzia-id_agente-flag_storico-deleted   4   const   60384   7.57    Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

it takes 0.0975 seconds. **Unbelievable**

Someone could help me understand why those improvements happenend?

Comment: `(clienti.cognome LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.nome LIKE '%marco%' OR ... OR clienti.cell LIKE '%marco%' OR clienti.fax LIKE '%marco%')` may be replaced with `(CONCAT_WS(',', clienti.cognome, clienti.nome, ... , clienti.cell, clienti.fax) LIKE '%marco%')`. And create index by `(id_agenzia, clienti.deleted, cognome, nome, cliente_id)`. And renew table' statistic.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! could you please explain why my last email uses indexes while previous versions not?

Comment: The execution plan builder / optimizer has a limited amount of time for its work. So it may simply not have enough time to consider the best execution plan, and therefore will be used the most optimal plan from considered ones. In addition, the available statistics of the table on which the plan is based may not correspond to the actual content of the table.